# Sentence with "auto" possessive

Tags: possessives

Consider the following English sentence:

> *I explained John's and Arthur's progress.*

What would be the best (*i.e.* more elegant) way to change it if, instead of Arthur (or John), the 2nd person was myself? I was thinking of "*I explained John's and my progress*" but it just doesn't sound right to me ( I am a non-native English speaker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I explained John's progress and my progress" would be the best way to avoid any confusion about whether you are speaking about joint progress or individual progress.

See http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/PossessivesandAttributives/faq0032.html